# LinkedCell to Checkbox calling onAction Subroutine in VBA?

Tags: vba, checkbox, subroutine

I have a great number of checkboxes calling a subroutine whenever a checkbox is ticked/unticked. Now I would like to get the address to the linked cell of the checkbox that called the sub. I've tried

```
Application.Caller.LinkedCell
```

but I get "Object required" error, I  guess because Application.Caller returns a string.

Is there some way I can get the address of the linkedCell?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes you are using a `Checkbox` from the Forms menu, as I don't think `Application.Caller` recognizes an `ActiveX` control. It uses the oddly-named `ControlFormat` property of a `Shape` (A Checkbox is a Shape):

```
Sub GetLinkedCell()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim chk As ControlFormat

Set shp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes(Application.Caller)
Set chk = shp.ControlFormat
MsgBox chk.LinkedCell
End Sub
```